# If an button element is set to null then will the click listeners added to it are removed?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

In Xamarin Android, after the page is destroyed, i am setting the button element to null, is it ok to leave it or should i remove the click listener before making the button to null to avoid memory leak ?

Answer (score 0):

the listeners are not unsubscribed you would have to do that manually.... check out the documentation [microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768(v=vs.90).aspx)